# How to .slice changing parts of a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs that use bootstrap Grid system to allow users of the site to "zoom" content. 
In this example with the `class="abcd b1 col-lg-6"` everything works fine.
But then I have my `b1` part of the classes.. it will go up beyond `b10`, which makes my code no longer work. 
I have tried to change the code so it would read from right to left... but then when the `col-lg-6` becomes `col-lg-10` it no longer works either.

So my question: is there a better way to .slice the code so it will work even when my classes length changes?

```
<div id="col" class="abcd b1 col-lg-6"> //the div                   
    <div class="tn bg1"> 
        <div class="ca">              
            <div class="bp">

                <button type="button" id="plus" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Bigger Size"></button> //the button

                <button type="button" id="minus" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Smaller Size"></button>

            </div>   
        </div><!--ca-->                             
    </div><!--tn-->            
</div><!--col-->

<!--Plus Button-->
```

```jquery
var className = ('col-lg-');       //make className = "col-lg-"

$('button#plus').click(function() {   //find button#plus and add clickfunction on it.
    $this = $(this).closest('div#col');   //find the div that shall change on click, closest div with id=col

    var counter = $this.attr('class').split(className)[1];  //get the last section of the class. class "col-lg-6" will set the counter to = 6
    var classList = $($this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);    //get all the classes of that div, in an objekt array stored in "classList3"
    var classString = classList.toString();                  //make that objekt array into a string. classstring = "abcd,b1,col-lg-6"
    var oldClass = classString.slice(8);                    //slice out the part i want. oldClass = "col-lg-6"
    var nextNum = 1;

    if (counter != '')                   //if the counter has already started
        nextNum = parseInt(counter) + 2;     //add +2 on click

    if (counter < 12) {                   //if counter are less then 12
        $this.removeClass(oldClass).addClass(className + nextNum);    //Remove class "col-lg-6" (or what ever the number are at the moment)
    }
    else {                               //if counter are bigger or = 12
                                         //do nothing
    }
})
```

Comment: Try refactoring your code using `.hasClass()` instead. It's unreliable to assume the classes will be listed in a certain order.

Comment: Thank you, i will lock into that. Was just hoping that i did not need to rewrite all the code. Seems like i was wrong :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it :)

First i add the variable:

```
var otherClasses = $this.attr('class').split(className)[0];
```

This variable store the other classes " abcd b1 ", not the " col-lg-6 "

Then i changed this:

```
 $this.removeClass(oldClass).addClass(className + nextNum);
```

To this:

```
$this.removeClass().addClass(otherClasses + className + nextNum);
```

This will remove all the classes and then add the old ones + the new one back.

And remove this completly, there are no need for it anymore.

```
var classList = $($this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
var classString = classList.toString(); 
var oldClass = classString.slice(8);
```